# Unity C# How to save object as variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to save the object which triggered as a variable and afterwards destroy it by pushing a key but I couldn't figure out how to save it as a variable.

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject)
         _canHit = true;
}
```

Edit: (Added the whole script to make it more understandable)

```cs
    //GameObject variable
    public GameObject collidedWith;

    //store the collided GameObject
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        collidedWith = other.gameObject;
    }

    private bool _canHit;
    //if can hit true make it false and do the task
    private void Update()
    {
        if (_canHit)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && collidedWith != null)
            {
                Destroy(collidedWith);
                _canHit = false;
                Debug.Log("Left");
            }
        }  
    }
    //set _canHit true if object enters trigger
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.attachedRigidbody)
            _canHit = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject)
            trigObj = other.gameObject()
    }
 
    //set _canHit false if object enters trigger
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.attachedRigidbody)
            _canHit = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a variable of type GameObject to store the collided GameObject:

```
public GameObject collidedWith;//GameObject variable
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    collidedWith = other.gameObject;//store the collided GameObject
}
private void Update(){
    //if the specified key is pressed and there is a collided GameObject, destroy the collided GameObject
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(keycodeForDestroying) && collidedWith != null){
        Destroy(collidedWith);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added, it gives compiler error, I also editted the question you can check the script if u want to, ty for your response

Comment: @jetrldz please copy-paste the compiler error message and tell us what line of code the line number of the error refers to

Comment: Type 'collisiondetectorleft' already defines a member called 'OnTriggerEnter' with the same parameter types you can find it by ctrl +f  "//set _canHit true if object enters trigger" under that line

Comment: okay I just fixed it thank you a lot

Comment: @jetrldz no problem, I have also added explanations for your compiler errors in another answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

For compile errors:

```
//set _canHit true if object enters trigger
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.attachedRigidbody)
        _canHit = true;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject)
        trigObj = other.gameObject()
}

//set _canHit false if object enters trigger
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.attachedRigidbody)
        _canHit = false;
}
```

`other` is a `Collider`. `other.attachedRigidbody` is a `Rigidbody`, not a `bool`. If statements require a `bool`, which is a statement that is either `true` or `false`. You probably meant to check if there is an attached rigidbody, you can do this with `other.attachedRigidbody != null`. As the [documentation for Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-attachedRigidbody.html) says, `attachedRigidbody`

> Returns null if the collider is attached to no rigidbody.

Another issue is in these lines:

```
if (other.gameObject)
        trigObj = other.gameObject()
```

similar to the `attachedRigidbody`, other.gameObject is not a `bool`. Use `other.gameObject != null`. In this case, I think this check is unnecessary, because if you collide with something, it must have a GameObject. Also, other.gameObject is a variable/property, not a method. Remove the `()` at the end of the line, they should only be there if it was a method.

Finally, you defined two `OnTriggerEnter` functions. You can put the code from the bottom one in the top one and delete the bottom one.

```
//set _canHit true if object enters trigger
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.attachedRigidbody){
        _canHit = true;
    }
    trigObj = other.gameObject;
}

//set _canHit false if object enters trigger
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.attachedRigidbody != null)
        _canHit = false;
}
```